# Assign multiple values based on key from dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

Please consider this dictionary

```
dict = {
    "AccessKey": {
        "UserName": "string",
        "AccessKeyId": "string",
        "Status": "Active | Inactive",
        "SecretAccessKey": "string",
        "CreateDate": "datetime(2015, 1, 1)",
    }
}
```

What would be a way to assign values of the specified keys in one line, to vars?

x, y = dict['AccessKey'][AccessKeyId']['SecretAccessKey']

A solution would be:

```
x = dict['AccessKey']['AccessKeyId']

y = dict['AccessKey']['SecretAccessKey']
```

Comment: You say "the return" but there is no return in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
x, y = map(dict['AccessKey'].__getitem__, ('AccessKeyId', 'SecretAccessKey'))
```

...but why? Code should aim for *readability* first. Unless you're doing code-golf, that is.

Comment: are you saying by readability that any programmer should be able to read it and not just people that know the map function? I am not doing code-golf, was just wondering how I'd do it. not experienced enough with python.

Comment: @Scilla, I meant that one-liners aren't necessarily easier to read than two or more lines of code. They also aren't necessarily faster or easier to _write_. They're often fun to write, though, but not necessarily fun to _read_.

Comment: i know what you mean by not easy read. probably you're right too when it come to not being faster, unless you really know what you're doing. Anyhow, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```py
from operator import itemgetter

dct = {
    "AccessKey": {
        "UserName": "string",
        "AccessKeyId": "string",
        "Status": "Active | Inactive",
        "SecretAccessKey": "string",
        "CreateDate": "datetime(2015, 1, 1)",
    }
}

keys = "AccessKeyId", "SecretAccessKey"
print(itemgetter(*keys)(dct["AccessKey"]))
```

Prints:

```py
('string', 'string')
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more readable answer than @ForceBru's:

```
x, y = (dict['AccessKey'][item] for item in ('AccessKeyId', 'SecretAccessKey'))
```

which uses generator comprehension instead of `map` (and avoids the ugly `.__getitem__`). However, I agree with @ForceBru -

> ...but why? Code should aim for readability first. Unless you're doing code-golf, that is.